# Auditing data changes in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find a highly efficient method of auditing changes to data in a table. Currently I am using a trigger that looks at the INSERTED and DELETED tables to see what rows have changed and inserts these changes into an Audit table.

The problem is this is proving to be very inefficient (obviously!). It's possible that with 3 thousand rows inserted into the database at one time (which wouldn't be unusual) that 215000 rows would have to be inserted in total to audit these rows.

What is a reasonable way to audit all this data without it taking a long time to insert in to the database? It needs to be fast!

Thanks.

Comment: Although I have offered you an answer below, just out of curiosity, how do 3000 inserts create 215000 audit rows? That's over 70 audit records per row!

Comment: @Barry - Because for each column a row is inserted in the audit table showing old and new values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A correctly written trigger should be fast enough.

You could also look at [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx)

- [Auditing in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

I quite often use [AutoAudit](http://autoaudit.codeplex.com/):

> AutoAudit is a SQL Server (2005, 2008, 2012) Code-Gen utility that creates
>   Audit Trail Triggers with:
>
> Created, CreatedBy, Modified, ModifiedBy, and RowVersion (incrementing
>   INT) columns to table
>
> Insert event logged to Audit table
>
> Updates old and new values logged to Audit table   Delete logs all
>   final values to the Audit table
>
> view to reconstruct deleted rows
>
> UDF to reconstruct Row History
>
> Schema Audit Trigger to track schema changes
>
> Re-code-gens triggers when Alter Table changes the table

**Update**: (Original edit was rejected, but I'm re-adding it):

A major upgrade to version 3.20 was released in November 2013 with these added features:

- Handles tables with up to 5 PK columns
- Performance improvements up to 90% faster than version 2.00
- Improved historical data retrieval UDF
- Handles column/table names that need quotename [ ]
- Archival process to keep the live Audit tables smaller/faster but retain the older data in archive AutoAudit tables

Comment: Though an old post but did you ever notice the performance tradeoff with AutoAudit? Curious about performance; will give it try.

Comment: I tried autoaudit after installing it,I have created 2 tables test1 and test2,then inserted a row in test1. After that when I execute `select * from Audit.AuditAllExclusions
select * from Audit.AuditBaseTables
select * from Audit.AuditDetail
select * from Audit.AuditDetailArchive
select * from Audit.AuditHeader
select * from Audit.AuditHeaderArchive
select * from Audit.AuditSettings
select * from Audit.SchemaAudit` then it does not show me that values are insrted in test1 table

Comment: is something else I am missing

Answer (score 1):

As others already mentioned - you can use Change Data Capture, Change Tracking, and Audit features in SQL Server, but to keep it simple and use one solution to track all SQL Server activities including these DML operations I suggest trying ApexSQL Comply. You can disable all other, and leave DML auditing option only
It uses a centralized repository for captured information on multiple SQL Server instances and their databases.

It would be best to read this article first, and then decide on using this tool:
http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/methods-for-auditing-sql-server-data-changes-part-9-the-apexsql-solution/

Answer (score 1):

### **SQL Server Notifications on insert update delete table change**

SqlTableDependency C# componenet provides the low-level implementation to receive database notification creating SQL Server Queue and Service Broker.

Have a look at http://www.sqltabledependency.it/

For any record change, SqlTableDependency's event handler will get a notification containing modified table record values as well as DML - insert, update, delete - change executed on your database table.

Answer (score 0):

You could allow the table to be self auditing by adding additional columns, for example:

For an INSERT - this is a new record and it's existence in the table is the audit itself.

With a DELETE - you can add columns like `IsDeleted BIT \ DeletingUserID INT \ DeletingTimestamp DATETIME` to your table.

With an UPDATE you add columns like `IsLatestVersion BIT \ ParentRecordID INT` to track version changes.